# No module named 'machine' while importing

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File C:\Users\jobsa\Downloads\lcd.py, line 1, in module     import machine ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine'

I am trying to make an LCD display text. I need the address of the LCD on a Raspberry Pi Pico.

Comment: If you're just running `import machine` that should always work.  You didn't post your code so I guess you're doing something more complicated and it's hard for anyone to debug it.  Can you post a [mcve]?  Also, what version of MicroPython are you using?  You can see it from `sys.version`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're running the python file directly on your computer, rather than the pico. In order to run it on the pico, you can use a variety of programs, and [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) is a good place to start. You'll have to configure it to run on the pico, here's a [Tom's Hardware tutorial](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-pico-setup#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Set%20Up%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi%20Pico,quick%20print%20function%20to%20say%20%E2%80%9CHello%20World.%E2%80%9D%20) that may help.